# Can Heroku handle more than one connection simultaneously (Sinatra on Thin)?

Tags: asynchronous, heroku, sinatra, thin

I'm reading the Heroku Routing article and confused by the following:

**One Connection at a Time**

*The heroku.com stack only supports single threaded requests. Even if your application were to fork and support handling multiple requests at once, **the routing mesh will never serve more than a single request to a dyno at a time.***

and later in the article ...

**Multiple Simultaneous Connections**

***The herokuapp.com routing stack can be used for async or multi-threaded apps that wish to handle more than one connection simultaneously.** Ruby webservers such as Goliath, Thin (with a suitable web framework such as Async Sinatra), or your own custom EventMachine web process are some examples. Node.js web apps (such as those built with Express) can almost always handle multiple connections in a single process, as can most Python, Java, Scala, and Clojure apps.*

Which one is it then? Or are the two bits talking about different things? (i.e, requests and connections are different)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're reading this:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing

Regardless of the processes you have running, the Heroku routing mesh will only issue one request to your application at a time, **on the Apsen and Bamboo stacks**.

On the Cedar stack though, you are allowed multiple simultaneous connections.

- Aspen / Bamboo is easily identified by *.heroku.com
- Cedar is
  identifiable by *.herokuapp.com

Comment: Ha! The article bears today's date! The old article was confusing, explaining my post. They've now separated it and the distinction is clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Which one is it then? Or are the two bits talking about different things? (i.e, requests and connections are different)

The two are indeed talking about different things, but not the different things you were thinking of.

The two are talking about Heroku's two different platforms, the Aspen/Bamboo platform at `*.heroku.com` and the Cedar platform at `*.herokuapp.com`.